# how to read a pdf417 decode with the pc web camera

Tags: angular, web, zxing, pdf417

I am trying to read a `pdf417` code with the computer's web camera using the `zxing library` in angular but I do not recognize the `pdf417` format, any idea of ​​how I can read this and extract the data from an identification card with the web camera from the browser?

I've tried the ZXing libraries forcing the code.

```
<zxing-scanner [formats] = "['PDF_417']" (scanComplete) = 'scanComplete ($event)'></ zxing-scanner>
scanComplete (value: Result) {if(value! = undefined) {console.log (value);}}
```

but the response doesn´t are correctly

I need with the web camera of the machine to be able to recognize the pdf417 code of an identification card and obtain in a variable the object that it returns or at least a chain of values ​​that allows me to use it to decrypt the data that has the code and I can handle it for my other forms.

Comment: <zxing-scanner 
        [formats] = "['PDF_417']"
        (scanComplete) = 'scanComplete ($event)'>
</ zxing-scanner>

scanComplete (value: Result) {
     if(value! = undefined){
           console.log (value);
  }
}

Comment: ZXing does not support `PDF417`. There exists a fork of `ZXing` on Github, which does support, though your photos have to be of an excellent quality. Or, alternatively, preprocessed.